# So was that Data Structures & Algorithms course really useful after all?

Tags: language-agnostic

I remember when I was in DSA I was like *wtf* O(n) and wondering where would I use it other than in grad school or if you're not a PhD like Bloch. Somehow uses for it does pop up in business analysis, so I was wondering when have you guys had to call up your **Big O** skills to see how to write an algorithm, which data structure did you use to fit or whether you had to actually create a new ds (like your own implementation of a splay tree or trie).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Honestly, being able to answer that stuff is my biggest criterion for taking interviewees seriously in an interview.  Knowing how basic data structures work, basic O(n) analysis, and some light theory is really crucial to being able to write large applications successfully.

It's important in the interview because it's important in the job.  I've worked with techs in the past that were self taught, without taking the data structures course or reading a data structures book, and their code is occasionally bad in ways they should have seen coming.

If you don't know that n2 is going to run slowly compared to n log n, you've got more to learn.

As far as the later half of the data structures courses, it isn't generally applicable to most tech jobs, but if you ever do wind up needing it, you'll wish you had paid more attention.

Answer (score 12):

Understanding Data Structures has been fundamental to many of the projects I've worked on, and that goes beyond the ten minute song 'n dance one does when asked such a question in an interview situation.

Granted that modern environments with all sorts of collection classes can make light work of storing and accessing large amounts of data, but having an understanding that a particular problem is best solved with a particular data structure can be a great timesaver. And by "timesaver" I mean "the difference between something working and not working".

Comment: +1 - Hate to see "deeper" issues in CS get relegated to "don't care unless there is an interview."  You are right to point out that a professional will understand that they have real-world implications as well.

Answer (score 6):

Big-O notation is one of the basic notations used when describing algorithms implemented by a particular library. For example, all documentation on STL that I've seen describes various operations in terms of big-O, so naturally you have to e.g. understand the difference between O(1), O(log n) and O(n) to understand the implications of your choice of STL containers and algorithms. MSDN also does that for .NET classes, and IIRC Java documentation does that for standard Java classes. So, I'd say that knowing the notation is pretty much a requirement for understanding documentation of most popular frameworks out there.

Answer (score 3):

Sure (even though I'm a humble MS in EE -- no PhD, no CS, differently from my colleague Joshua Block), I write a lot of stuff that needs to be highly scalable (or components that may need to be reused in highly scalable apps), so big-O considerations are most always at work in my design (and it's not hard to take them into account). The data structures I use are almost always from Python's simple but rich supply (which I did lend a hand developing;-), rarely is a totally custom one needed (rather than building on top of list, dict, etc); but when it does happen (e.g. the bitvectors in my open source project gmpy), no big deal.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use B-Trees right when I learned about them in algorithm class (that was about 15 years ago when there were much less open source implementations available). And even later the knowledge about the differences of e. g. container classes came in handy...

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely: even though stacks, queues, etc. are pretty straightforward, it helps to have been introduced to them in a disciplined fashion.

B-Tree's and more advanced sorting are a bit more difficult so learning them early was a big benefit and I have indeed had to implement each of them at various points.

Finally, I created an algorithm for single-connected components a few years back that was significantly better than the one our signal-processing team was using but I couldn't convince them that it *was* better until I could show that it was O(n) complexity rather than O(nlogn).

...just to name a few examples.

Of course, if you are content to remain a CRUD-system hacker with no real desire to do more than collect a paycheck, then it may not be necessary...

Answer (score 1):

I found my knowledge of data structures very useful when I needed to implement a customizable event-driven system about ten years ago.  That's the biggie, but I use that sort of knowledge fairly frequently in lesser ways.

Answer (score 1):

For me, knowing the exact algorithms has been... nice as background knowledge. However, the thing that's been the most useful is the more general background of having to pay attention to how different pieces of an algorithm interact. For instance, there can be places in code where moving one piece of code (ie, outside a loop) can make a huge difference in both time and space.

Its less of the specific knowledge the course taught and, rather, more that it acted like several years of experience. The course took something that might take years to encounter (have drilled into you) all the variations of in pure "real world experience" and condensed it.

Answer (score 1):

The title of your question asks about data structures and algorithms, but the body of your question focuses on complexity analysis, so I'll focus on that too:

There are lots of programming jobs where being able to do complexity analysis is at least occasionally useful. See [What career can I hope for if I like algorithms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202128/what-career-can-i-hope-for-if-i-like-algorithms/1202216#1202216) for some examples of these.

I can think of several instances in my career where either I or a co-worker have discovered a a piece of code where the (usually time, sometimes space) complexity was higher that it should have been. eg: something that was quadratic or cubic when it could have been linear or nlog(n). Such code would work fine when given small inputs, but on larger inputs would quickly become *really* slow or consume all available memory. Knowing alternative algorithms and data structures, their complexities, and also how to analyze the complexity to build new algorithms is vital in being able to correct these problems (or avoid them in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

Networking is all I've used it: in an implementation of traveling salesman.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do a lot of "line of business" and "forms over data" apps, so most problems I work on can be solved by hammering together arrays, linked lists, and hash tables. However, I've had the chance to work my data structures magic here and there:

- Due to weird complex business rules, I worked on an application which used a custom thread pool implemented as a leftist-heap.
- My dev team struggled to write a complex multithreaded app. It was plagued with race conditions, dead locks, and lousy performance due to very fine-grained locking. We re-worked the code to share state between threads, opting to write a very light-weight wrapper to facilitate message passing. Next, we converting our linked lists and hash tables to immutable stacks and immutable style and immutable red-black trees, we had no more problems with thread safety or performance. The resulting code was immaculate and surprisingly readable.
- Frequently, a  business rules engine requires you to roll your own state machine, which is very naturally modelled as a graph where vertexes and states and edges are transitions between states.

If for no other reasons, I'm glad I took the time to readable about data structures and algorithms simply to be able picture novel problems a little differently, especially combinatorial problems and graph problems. Graph theory is no longer a synonym for "scary".